# Do harmful but non-damaging spells cause a character to wake up?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Do harmful spells (specifically [Bestow Curse](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/bestowCurse.html#bestow-curse)) that don't do damage cause people to wake from normal sleep?

Does any damage cause a character to wake up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, there is no such rule

Being automatically awoken requires that you be hit or hurt. *Bestow curse* does not apply a wound; its effects are spiritual and tied to your fate or luck. You don’t automatically know you’ve been affected by it, which as a rule of thumb generally means it doesn’t automatically wake you.

The casting of the spell itself may wake someone, since speaking in a strong voice right next to someone is presumably a DC 0 Perception check (i.e. the check necessary to understand a conversation), and while being asleep does increase the DC by 10, that still only results in a DC 10 check. But the caster could simply cast the spell somewhere else, and hold the charge to bring it to the target.

I really do not think the touch itself is sufficient to wake someone. Waking someone is described as a slap or an intentional shaking; a touch is just that, a touch. Anyone who’s prodded someone to get them to roll over or stop snoring knows you can touch someone who is sleeping without waking them.

On the other hand, effects that are not HP-damage may qualify as wounds. Most forms of ability damage (rather than the ability reduction of *bestow curse*) or energy drain, for instance. Most things that stun, stagger, or daze, most likely. So in some cases, non-damaging spells may wake someone automatically. I just don’t think *bestow curse* is one of them.

Comment: I feel like mentioning Silent spell might also have some merit here.

Comment: +1: Good clear answer. I was also thinking of holding the charge, so you could just sneak up after casting the spell before hand.

Answer (score 2):

## GM Ruling

- I would rule **Yes** based on the Touch range required.
- (If it was a ranged spell such as [Enlarge Person](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/enlargePerson.html), I would rule no.)

Pathfinder doesn't have direct rules for standard sleep, so the following information has been taken from the [Sleep Spell](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/sleep.html)

> Slapping or wounding awakens an affected creature, but normal noise does not. Awakening a creature is a standard action (an application of the aid another action).

While the spell [Bestow Curse](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/spells/bestowCurse.html#bestow-curse) doesn't directly affect the target in a way that would wake them up, it has a range of touch.  Based on that this is a standard rest, and not magically caused, I would rule that any touch would awaken a seasoned adventurer sleeping outdoors.

As this isn't specifically defined anywhere, an amount of GM Fiat is required, if the sleeping victim is asleep in a comfortable bed, or was induced to sleep, (Via a tonic or spell), then it would make sense that they would be much more difficult to awaken.

*EDIT:*
Bestow Curse and Enlarge Person both have a (V)Verbal component.  According to the seciont on [Magic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html):

> Verbal (V): A verbal component is a spoken incantation. To provide a verbal component, you must be able to speak in a strong voice.

There's no indication of of the volume of a strong voice, though outside of any touch based rulings, I would ask for a [Perception Check](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/perception.html) at DC+10 (Sleeping) against a stealth check made by caster to try and keep a low voice.  Of course, casting the spell at range and holding the charge would eliminate this check as well.

At the very least, based on hearing for the sound of a creature walking while sleeping, the character should have a Perception DC20 to be awoken by the creature approaching.

Comment: To add to this from a more RP standpoint: I would say that they could hear the spell go off (VS in the description for "curse")and because you have to physically touch the person also the "Energy" of the spell going into them (Will save), I would give them a chance to hear the spell go off with all regular rules of non-magical sleep and being woken up adding someone lightly touched them to the DC (In favor of the one being asleep).

Comment: Since you edited to give an awesome answer ill add a group thing we do here (This is all house rules but kinda make sense to my players):

In the world I run the spells are NOT quiet until your high level making almost all spells near your casting level loud (Think "Thou Shall Not Pass!!!"). Only when you are 5 levels past a spell's level do you have a chance to not yell and 9 to whisper them under breath. Makes silent spell feat useful. Also I have a house rule people can use a feat to make a number of spells quieted (like the spell mastery rules) and i call it hushed spell feat.

Comment: Pathfinder has rules for sleeping characters to be awoken by sound, anyway (+10 to the Perception DC, which would presumably be a DC 0 base for being a strong voice right next to the target – though the caster could always cast the spell well away from the target, and simply hold the charge), so that much should be updated to match the rules rather than your on-the-spot call (you can include both but a good answer should at least acknowledge the rules). As for touch = wake, the description suggests not so much: a touch is not a slap, and does not cause a wound.

Comment: I would argue that especially seasoned adventurers sleeping outside would not be woken up by a slight touch. Think of insects landing on or crawling over your face.

Comment: +1- For understanding that adventurers who sleep like the dead would already be there. As majestic stated, spells that have a verbal component should require at the minimum a normal speaking voice. If you could whisper under your breath silent spell would be utterly useless.